# In CSS, how to select a particular tag under mutiple ids?

Tags: css

I have 5 fieldsets which has unique IDs. I want to give a particular styling to all the input tags in it. For example:
    #fieldset-long1,#fieldset-long2,#fieldset-long3,#fieldset-long4,#fieldset-long5{style for fieldset}

Now to give style to the inputs in these 5 field sets, I will have to write `#fieldset-long1 input,#fieldset-long2 input,#fieldset-long3 input{style for input}`.

Just wondering if there is an easier CSS selector to specify the parents of a tag that I want to apply styles to.

HTML for fieldset:

```
<fieldset id="fieldset-long1">
<dt><label for="email">Email:</label></dt>
<dd><input type="text" name="email" id="email" value="" tabindex="3" /></dd>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: Can't you add a CSS class to all those input elements?

Comment: No. The fieldsets are printed with from PHP code that I do not want to touch as it inside a class written by someone else...

Comment: Can you add the class via javascript?

Comment: Can you identify the fieldsets by their parent?

Comment: No. These may be under different parents.

Comment: Can you show us the html that is being generated?

Comment: Can you use jQuery for styling? I know, it's an overkill.

Comment: Yeah, I am specifying the dimensions of the inputs. So using javascript - an overkill... :)

Comment: I have added the HTML code generated for fieldset

Comment: Thanks Jan and Jrod for trying to help. The answer seems to be - no. We can't do that kind of selection with plain CSS. Answer from Behnam Esmaili seems to be the closest to the requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with css lower than 3 it is not possible but with css3 you can do something like this :

```
fieldsets [id^="fieldset"] input{/* style for input*/ }
```

Comment: So can OR be spcified in that condition? fieldsets [id="fieldset1" || id="fieldset2"] or something like that? Thank you...

Comment: @Vishnu no, I don't think so.

Comment: @JanDvorak changed it as well.

Comment: @Vishnu no you can't.see css3 selectors here http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/200601/css_3_selectors_explained/

Comment: if you want to select elements with more complicated criteria you must stick with jquery.

Comment: @vishnu You can do this:  `fieldset[id^="fieldset1"] input, fieldset[id^="fieldset2"] input`.  It seems a bit unnecessary, since `fieldset[id^=fieldset]` will catch anything where the fieldset's id begins with the phrase "fieldset".

Comment: @cimmanon it is still possible (and not unlikely) that `fieldset[id^="fieldset"]` selects more than intended.